# How to add custom legend in rechart?

Tags: recharts

I've pie chart for that I want to add custom legend, As of now from rechart I got legend like this but how to customized it?

Existing
[image]

I want legend like this:

[image]

Someone please help,Thank you

Answer (score 8):

You can use content property in order to render a custom legend, like this:

```
<Legend iconType="circle" content={<RenderCusomizedLegend />} />
```

here is an example of use:
https://gist.github.com/abhirathore2006/7fa73328be7ff45b785d727fb19fffa6

also you can read more abou that in recharts documentation :
http://recharts.org/en-US/api/Legend